# Check if Clipboard Open

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I have used the code `Application.ShowClipboard` to open the clipboard on opening Word. However, this code also closes the clipboard if it is already open.

Therefore, I need to know how to check if the clipboard is already open to know whether to execute the code.

```
If Clipboard is open
Then Application.ShowClipboard
Else
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Clipboard is part of the `Applciation.Commandbars` collection.

Check to see if `Application.CommandBars("ClipBoard").Visible = False` and then `ShowClipboard` else, do nothing.

**Note:** This was tested on Word in Office 365.

```
Sub CheckForClipboard()
If Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard").Visible = False Then
    Application.ShowClipboard
Else
    'Do nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is:

```
Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard").Visible = True
```